# Html POST method not working

Tags: java, html, post

Why is my method does not work?
My Java code:

```
@POST
@Path("/request=PostStage")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getStagePOST(@QueryParam("fn")String fn,
    @QueryParam("tn")String tn,
    @QueryParam("stat")String stat,
    @QueryParam("length")String length,
    @QueryParam("lon")String lon,
    @QueryParam("lat")String lat,
    @QueryParam("crgw")String crgw,
    @QueryParam("lane")String lane) throws SQLException{
    return "Lat: " + lat + " lon: " + lon + " crgw: " + crgw;
}
```

My HTML code:

```html
<form action="http://localhost:9090/services/stage/request=PostStage" method="POST">   
    <p>Localization:</p>
    <p> fn : <input  name="fn" /></p>
    <p> tn : <input  name="tn" /></p>
    <p>stat : <input  name="stat" /></p>
    <p>length : <input name="length" /></p> 
    <p>Geoposition:</p>
    <p>lon : <input name="lon" /></p>
    <p>lat : <input name="lat" /></p>
    <P> Other:</P>
    <p>crgw :  <input name = "crgw" /></p>
    <p> lane : <input  name="lane" /></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Searchh" />
</form>
```

I give examples of parameters in a html page: lon - 12, lat - 12 etc.
As a result, I get:

```
Lat: null lon: null crgw: null
```

Why?

I can not find the problem :(

Very thanks for all answers .

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't there be types on the input-tags, like `<input name="lon" type="text" />`?

Also verify that the POST from the form really contains the parameters, the browser debugging IDE in both Chrome and Firefox is probably able to see how the POST-request looks.

Comment: if there is no type, browsers auto make inputs as text.

Answer (score 0):

Working! My mistake was to use "@QueryParam" instead "@FormParam".